# How to Set a gridview column width when binding to a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridviewcolumn

I am binding a table to a gridview in asp.net as such

```
grdIssues.DataSource = mdtIssues;

grdIssues.DataBind();
```

The problem is I cannot then control the column width, asp.net seems to decided on it's own what width each column should be. Methods such as

```
 grdIssues.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Width = 100;
 grdIssues.Columns[1].ItemStyle.Width = 100;
```

don't work because the columns are created dynamically. I cannot believe there isn't a way to do this short of manually creating each column and filling each row.

Answer (score 6):

You dont have to manually create the columns to set them the width, you can do this

```
 foreach (DataControlField column in OrdersGV.Columns)
    {
      column.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
    }
```

Comment: This fails to compile I get exception

Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ItemStyle' and no extension method 'ItemStyle' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I just edit the answer you, please try it. Make sure you do this after databinding your grid

Answer (score 3):

I was able to change the width of a certain `Gridview` column (bound to a `Datatable`) with the `RowDataBound` event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes["width"] = "200px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to answer my own question whenever I can so future users searching the thread will find the answer.

I could not find a way to do what I wanted directly. However I found if I define the columns myself, I could change the properties. In this example, I wanted to center the column data. Something like this.

```
BoundField bdfRaisedDate = new BoundField();
clsUtilities.SetBoundFieldCenter(ref bdfRaisedDate, "RaisedDateShort",    "Opened", "RaisedDate");

grdIssues.Columns.Add(bdfRaisedDate);

grdIssues.DataSource = mdtIssues;

grdIssues.DataBind();

public static void SetBoundFieldCenter(ref BoundField bdfAny, string pDataField, string pHeadingValue, string  pSortExpression)
{
      bdfAny.DataField = pDataField;
      bdfAny.HeaderText = pHeadingValue;
      bdfAny.SortExpression = pSortExpression;
      bdfAny.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
      bdfAny.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it as:

```
gridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Attributes["Width"] = "100px";
gridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Attributes["Width"] = "50px";
gridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Attributes["Width"] = "200px";
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it like this:

```
foreach (DataControlField field in grdIssues.Columns)
{
  field.HeaderStyle.Width = 100;
}
```

Comment: This compile by does not work. Only the one column that I added manually, a button, is in the collection of columns.

Bob

Comment: What event are you running the code in? You can't do it in Page_Load. Use grdIssues's Databound event.

Comment: the above code does not work for me too. How can we handle this?