# How fix width length of cell in Gridview

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

My code :

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("#", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("OrderID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("info", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
          dt.Rows.Add(i,"date","OrderID","info")
        }
```

I want to fix width of cell in every Rows of Gridview
and when my text is full of width my text will be wrap newline. thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set a gridview column width when binding to a datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740841/how-to-set-a-gridview-column-width-when-binding-to-a-datatable)

Comment: There are already lots of post in SO regarding this.

Comment: Thank you. Can i ask some question?

Comment: I cannot use <br /> for adding new line
* i already use HtmlEncode="False"

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br

Answer (score 0):

In c# winform gridview there WrapMode property that  can meet your need

```
dgvmydgv.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode =DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

thus for your case if the gridview is dt then

dt.DefaultCellStle.Wrapmode=DataDataGridViewTriState.True;
newline is applied to every texts that exceed the width

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set

`DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells`

(along with what you have done) for word-wrap to work.

with Wrap Mode To work